# How to find proper codepint for IconData?

Tags: flutter

How to find proper codepint for IconData?

The example below uses 0xe808 codepoint.

From where the codepoint data comes?

```
static const _kFontFam = 'TikTokIcons';
static const IconData chat_bubble = const IconData(0xe808, fontFamily: _kFontFam);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Unicode code point at which this icon is stored in the icon font.

So you need font tools such as Windows Character Map or online tools like [fontdrop.info](https://fontdrop.info/) to view font metadata;

[image: view with Characeter Map]

[image: view with fontdrop.info]

```
  static const IconData add = IconData(0xe145, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');
```